# Separate compilation with abstract classes C++

Tags: c++, oop

I have a question in regards to building a project in C++ with abstract classes.

Suppose you have an abstract class A in a header file and then you have class B in a cpp file to create an object from class A. So far we have:

Class_A.h, Class_B.cpp

Within the Class_B.cpp file, I have included the header Class_A.h.

I want to now create objects of Class_B in a main file, for example: main.cpp. I added the header Class_A.h in main.cpp and when compiled, I get 'Class_B’ was not declared in this scope as an error. All files are in the same directory. I'm not too sure how to fix this or whether or not I am not using abstract classes correctly. All the examples I found online did something along the lines of: defining Class_B inside main.cpp without creating a separate cpp file for Class_B.

Example:

Abstract class: Car.h

Instance of abstract class: Toyota.cpp

main.cpp:

```
#include 'Car.h'

...

Toyota new_car = new Toyota(...);
```

Comment: You have to declare whatever you wish to use. You should also pair `Class_B.cpp` with `Class_B.h` where you only *declare* stuff that's defined in the `.cpp` file. You then should `#include <Class_B.h>` in your `main.cpp` file.

Comment: define Class_B in Class_B.h and `#include` that in main.cpp

Comment: @Fureeish hmmm? Class_B is supposed to be an instance of Class_A. For example, we have abstract class Car, then Class_B in this scenario would be Toyota. So, I'm not too sure why we need to create another header file for Class_B when Class_A should cover this?

Comment: @yano What I said above I guess could be a response to you

Comment: You can *implement* Class_B in a separate C++ file, but if you intend to use it in another file you must declare it, usually in a .h file.

Comment: @jkb That's so strange.... Doesn't that defeat the purpose of making Class_A.h in the first place? So, if I implement Class_A.h with Class_B.cpp, I would still need a header (Class_B.h) to use it elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to organize your code.  There's no hard and fast rules about how that needs to be done, but generally you define classes in header files (.h or .hpp) and implement the class in source files (.cpp).  In this situation I would:

Class_A.h

```
class Class_A
{
public:
  virtual void myFunc() = 0;  // Class_A is abstract
  ...
}
```

Class_B.h

```
#include "Class_A.h"
class Class_B : public Class_A
{
public:
  void myFunc();
  ...
}
```

Class_B.cpp

```
Class_B::myFunc()
{
  ...
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Class_B.h"
int main()
{
  Class_B myClassB;
  myClassB.myFunc();
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

And of course you need to feed all the source files to your compiler correctly, at least Class_B.cpp and main.cpp in this case.